# Polymer with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to control my polymer text box with input type text, this textbox is being used to receive a users Phone number

```
<paper-input 
    name="phone" 
    id="phone" 
    value="{{Request::old('phone')}}" 
    label="Phone Number" 
    aria-disabled="false" 
    class="x-scope paper-input-0" 
    style="text-align: left" 
    required auto-validate error-message="Phone Number cannot be Blank!">
    <!--Text area to obtain phone number -->    
    <input type="text" is="iron-input" min="10" maxlength="10"  size="10"/>

</paper-input>
```

what i'm trying to do with this is actually use javascript with polymer to limit this text box input to simply just numbers with a minimum input requirement set by me.

I had a couple of rough attempts at it but i'm fairly new to polymer so none of the approaches i took worked.

any tips would help !

thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

`<paper-input>` is not designed to wrap a regular `<input />` element. You would use `<paper-input-container>` for that.

In your case, use the paper input to limit characters directly:

```
<paper-input 
name="phone" 
id="phone" 
value="{{Request::old('phone')}}" 
label="Phone Number" 
aria-disabled="false" 
class="x-scope paper-input-0" 
style="text-align: left" 
required auto-validate error-message="Phone Number cannot be Blank!" 
minlength="10"
maxlength="10"  
size="10">
</paper-input>
```